# White line appear on navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set the color of my navigation bar through `AppDelegate` and setting a solid color box as the background image. This is the code i used:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];


[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];

return YES;
}
```

Surprisingly i get a white line in the middle of the navigation bar. Keep in mind that i have used the exactly same method in another application and everything worked fine. This is what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your View Controller is under the NavigationController. I bet you don't set navigationController for your viewController.

BTW, If you want to use white status style, you need to change "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally realized what was wrong. I forgot to add the @2x photo. It was resizing a small photo since i am running my application on iphone5s.